# Stateful application on Google's app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm in the need to run a Geth node on GCP. I was debating between using a VM instance and running the node in there or trying App Engine Flexible Env, I went with the latter, not using K8s because of other reasons. Everything is ok with App Engine but the thing I'm just noticing is that I don't have the ability to save data on disk (Sort of like a `PersistentVolumeClaim` on K8s) I see that we can have volumes but those are temporary while I need one that persists between versions and everything, this is because syncing the blockchain takes some time and ideally I wouldn't be doing this every-time we deploy a new version, you can specify a data directory where all the imported blocks will be saved to and retrieved in case it needs to, is that possible on App Engine?

Comment: No, you will have to use some sort of storage API to persist anything - for example Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thank you @mensi

Comment: @mensi. I encourage you to post your comment as an answer for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - App Engine is a "serverless" offering in the sense that you get dynamically scaled, ephemeral instances running with your code. For data storage, you have to use a suitable API. For your use-case, it sounds like two options look interesting:

- [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage): Better for large, less dynamic data you can afford to access with slightly higher latency.
- [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore): Better for small, highly dynamic data you need to access with low latency